# can't compile FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to make simple chat application for Android. For this I need to import FirebaseUI class to the project. I'm facing the problem, that many people had before, but still following all their decisions, cant solve this problem. I try to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui.firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```

I'm following all instructions, like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

adding maven url:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and AndroidManifest:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

Still get the Error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui.firebase-ui:1.2.0:

Can someone help please? I applied all the solutions described before and dont understand, what the problem? Maybe i should just create new project, due to the i changed that one so many times with so many errors in building gradle?)

Comment: Try using `mavenCentral()` repository. It [contains](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.firebaseui%22) the `1.1.0` and lower versions.

Comment: @Dmitriy Do you mean just replacing in  `allprojects {}` section `maven` on `mavencentral`? And what about `1.1.0`? Is there any way to use the latest version?

Comment: Just add `mavenCentral()` to the `repositories` section. This is where Gradle takes the artifacts from.

Comment: don't forget that this line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 should be at the end of the gradle file after the closing brackets

Comment: You have a typo in there: `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'`. It may be hard to spot, but you need to have a colon (`:`) after `com.firebaseui`.

Comment: Thank you all, guys! The problem was in `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'`. It;s really hard to find, but i could notice it by syntax. Also, Dmitriy, thanks for the `mavenCentral()`. I think it will be useful in future